# How to calculate standard deviation using a pandas series that isn't recognizing the data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of the mean for a given item. I am having issues using the specific item because the data frame is not recognizing the attribute. The output now is giving `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item'`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['drills', 0.0354],['drills', 0.391304],['drills', 0.439024], ['screws', .0047],['screws', 0.163870]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['item', 'rate'])

grouping = df.groupby(['item'])['rate']

calculations = grouping.agg(['size', 'mean', 'std'])

math = calculations.loc[calculations.item]['mean'] - .05

v=pd.DataFrame(math)

test = (2 * v.loc[v.item == 'drills']['std'])
```

The Output I want is the test variable value. I want to be able to run this over an entire data frame without specifying where `v.item = 'drills'`

Comment: Please share the actual output and the desired output and in case of an error the full trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['drills', 0.0354],['drills', 0.391304],['drills', 0.439024], ['screws', .0047],['screws', 0.163870]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['item', 'rate'])

mean_=df.groupby(by='item').mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'rate' : 'mean'})
std_=df.groupby(by='item').std().reset_index().rename(columns={'rate' : 'std'})
count_=df.groupby(by='item').count().reset_index().rename(columns={'rate' : 'count'})
df=pd.concat([mean_, std_['std']], axis=1)
df=pd.concat([df, count_['count']], axis=1)
df
```

Comment: When i try to do the mean off this data frame I get an error. math = mean_.loc[mean_.item]['mean'] - .05

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Index(['drills', 'screws'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: But with the dataframe you have as an output from my code you already have then mean, no ?